# Will this make a faster parallel stream?

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

The OCP book says that all streams are ordered by default but that it is possible to turn an ordered stream into an unordered stream using the unordered() method.

It also says that this method can greatly improve performance when I use this method as an intermediate operation before calling the parallel() terminal operation. My question is: Will the below parallelstream be faster then the one below that one?

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6).stream().unordered().parallel()

Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6).parallelStream().
```

PS: I know a parallelstream doesent increase performance when working with a small collection, but lets pretend we are working with a very large collection here.

The second stream is still ordered right? So will the first one have better performance?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state that all streams are ordered by default: that's not the case. For example if your source is a `HashSet`, the resulting stream will not be ordered.

Regarding your question on making a parallel stream unordered to "greatly improve performance": as always when it comes to performance, it depends (on the terminal operation, on the intermediate operations, on the size of the stream etc.)

[The `java.util.stream` package javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) gives some pointers that answer your question, at least in part:

> For parallel streams, relaxing the ordering constraint can sometimes enable more efficient execution. Certain aggregate operations, such as filtering duplicates (`distinct()`) or grouped reductions (`Collectors.groupingBy()`) can be implemented more efficiently if ordering of elements is not relevant. Similarly, operations that are intrinsically tied to encounter order, such as `limit()`, may require buffering to ensure proper ordering, undermining the benefit of parallelism. In cases where the stream has an encounter order, but the user does not particularly care about that encounter order, explicitly de-ordering the stream with `unordered()` may improve parallel performance for some stateful or terminal operations. However, most stream pipelines, such as the "sum of weight of blocks" example above, still parallelize efficiently even under ordering constraints.

Comment: Also, for more info on encounter order: http://www.lambdafaq.org/in-what-order-do-the-elements-of-a-stream-become-available/ They also conclude that possible performance improvements depend on what you do with the stream afterwards.

Comment: @Malte Hartwig: of course, it depends on the subsequent operation, a) if they weren’t already unordered in the first place, b) whether there is a way to benefit from the unorderedness. With the current Java 8 reference implementation, I couldn’t find *any* example where chaining `.unordered()` made a difference. (Not to confuse with using `findAny()` instead of `findFirst()`, etc. These *have* an effect)…

Answer (score 1):

For the case that you have shown here, **absolutely not**. There are way too few elements here. Generally you should measure and then conclude, but this one is almost a no-brainer.

Also read this: [Parallel Processing](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html)

The thing about `unordered` is that *while* executing the terminal operation, the Stream pipeline has to mention order - that means additional costs. If there is no order to maintain, the stream is faster.

Notice that once you called `unordered` there is no way to get that order back. You could sort, but that might not mean the initial order.

Same goes for `findFirst` for example and `findAny` in a parallel process.